# How to fix IFrame error in directus and nextjs in draft mode?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, iframe, next.js13, directus

i am using nextjs my next.conf.js look like this

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    headers() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/(.*)',
                headers: securityHeaders,
            },
        ];
    },
};

const ContentSecurityPolicy = `
    default-src 'self';
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';
    child-src 'self';
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
    img-src * blob: data:;
    media-src 'none';
    connect-src *;
    font-src 'self' data:;
    frame-src 'self' localhost:8085;
    frame-ancestors 'self' localhost:8085;
`;

const securityHeaders = [
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP
    {
        key: 'Content-Security-Policy',
        value: ContentSecurityPolicy.replace(/\n/g, ''),
    },
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy
    {
        key: 'Referrer-Policy',
        value: 'origin-when-cross-origin',
    },
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options
    {
        key: 'X-Content-Type-Options',
        value: 'nosniff',
    },
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-DNS-Prefetch-Control
    {
        key: 'X-DNS-Prefetch-Control',
        value: 'on',
    },
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security
    {
        key: 'Strict-Transport-Security',
        value: 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload',
    },
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy
    {
        key: 'Permissions-Policy',
        value: 'camera=(), microphone=(), geolocation=()',
    },
];

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

i already define the frame-src and frame-ancestors and also try remove one and try with only one option but still in localhost:8085 i got the error

```js
Refused to frame 'http://localhost:3000/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' localhost:8085".
```

[image]

i am using directus as cms and using the preview feature in directus and in nextjs using draft feature to show real time changes

Answer (score 1):

i just want to replace `frame-ancestors 'self' localhost:8085;` to `frame-ancestors 'self' localhost:*;` and works like a charm

previous ContentSecurityPolicy

```js
const ContentSecurityPolicy = `
    default-src 'self';
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';
    child-src 'self';
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
    img-src * blob: data:;
    media-src 'none';
    connect-src *;
    font-src 'self' data:;
    frame-src 'self' localhost:8085;
    frame-ancestors 'self' localhost:8085;
`;
```

after modify ContentSecurityPolicy that was work for me

```js
const ContentSecurityPolicy = `
    default-src 'self';
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';
    child-src 'self';
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
    img-src * blob: data:;
    media-src 'none';
    connect-src *;
    font-src 'self' data:;
    frame-ancestors 'self' localhost:*;
`;
```